# The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open. (Multiple Image Upload)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

While Uploading multiple images i was getting error as `Maximum request length exceeded` but When I increased the size from the `Web.Config` file now I am getting error as `The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.`
Dont know why.

Please check the code and do let me know where I am mistaken

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile == false)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", "<script>alert('Please select the file.')</script>", false);
        }

        else
        {
            foreach (var file in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/GalleryImages/" + filename));

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tbl_gallery_stack(gallery_id, image_title, image_description, image_path) values (@gallery_id,@image_title,@image_description,@image_path)", conn);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gallery_id", ddlImagesId.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_title", txtImageTitle.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_description", txtImageDescription.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_path", filename);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                BindGrid();
            }
        }
    }
```

My web.config file code:-

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1073741824" />
</system.web>
```

**Latest thing happening**

When I upload multiple image, I am not able to view in the gridview. And also in the table the multiple entries get inserted..

See the code:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdGalleryData"
                runat="server"
                Width="100%" border="1"
                Style="border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;"
                CellPadding="3"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                AllowPaging="True"
                PageSize="3"
                OnPageIndexChanging="grdGalleryData_PageIndexChanging"
                CssClass="hoverTable"
                DataKeyNames="Id"
                >
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <Columns>
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="k-grid td"></HeaderStyle>
                        <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="gallery_id" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="image_title" HeaderText="Gallery title" ItemStyle-Width="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="image_description" HeaderText="Gallery Description" ItemStyle-Width="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Images" ItemStyle-Width="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Image ID="imgDisplay" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Getimage(Eval("image_path").ToString()) %>' Width="100px" Height="100px" />
                      </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Also see the code behind:-

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile == false)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", "<script>alert('Please select the file.')</script>", false);
        }

        else
        {
            foreach (var file in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/GalleryImages/" + filename));

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tbl_gallery_stack(gallery_id, image_title, image_description, image_path) values (@gallery_id,@image_title,@image_description,@image_path)", conn);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gallery_id", ddlImagesId.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_title", txtImageTitle.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_description", txtImageDescription.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_path", filename);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                BindGrid();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    protected string Getimage(string img)
    {
        if (img != "")
            return ("~/GalleryImages/" + img);
        else
            return ("Images/noimg.gif");
    }
```

`BindGrid` method

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindDropdownlist();
            BindGrid();
        }
    }
    private void BindGrid()
    {
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Id, gallery_id, image_title, image_description, image_path from tbl_gallery_stack order by Id desc");
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    grdGalleryData.DataSource = dt;
                    grdGalleryData.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You never close the connection

Comment: Where are you actually closing your connection? An open connection can only execute one command at a time.

Comment: @DrewKennedy: where should I close the connection ?

Comment: @RahulSutar after you executed the query but you can also use `using` for your connection.

Comment: @Sybren: I did that, but I am unable to view multiple images in my gridview.

Comment: @RahulSutar which errors or problems are you experiencing?

Comment: @Sybren: Now no error, but I can only view one image..the entry is getting inserted twice for two images uploaded at a time

Comment: @RahulSutar Can you update your question above with as much information as you can provide regarding your new issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are looping over a collection of files and then inserting data to the database, please instantiate the connection within a using block(so that it would be disposed properly) and also if you want to see all those images uploaded at a time in Grid, then I suggest you move BindGrid() function out of the ForEach loop.

Some sample code below:

```
foreach (var file in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
{
     try
     {
          string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

          file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/GalleryImages/" + filename)); //Save each file to disk.

          //Also please evaluate you requirement and if you are supposed to loop over relatively 
          // large collection then you can opt for some batch insert/update of records at-a-go 
          // instead of calling database multiple times, if your database offer support.
          using(var conn = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING VALUE HERE"))
          using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tbl_gallery_stack(gallery_id,image_title, image_description, image_path) values (@gallery_id,@image_title,@image_description,@image_path)", conn))
          {
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gallery_id", ddlImagesId.SelectedValue);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_title", txtImageTitle.Text);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_description", txtImageDescription.Text);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_path", filename);
                 conn.Open();
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
     }
     catch(Exception ex)  //I suggest you handle all those db/network specific exceptions first
     {
        //Log the exception details here and either continue over the loop or return based on application requirement.
     }

}

BindGrid(); //Assuming you are getting data from database inside this method and binding to Grid.
```

Also to ensure data integrity it would be better if you move disk file storage logic to end of the loop perhaps setting the entire database & file logic in a try catch block. So that if some error occur in database your disk file also won't be created unmapped.

Hope this may provide some help to your problem.

Comment: Can you please give me that in doing `try` `catch` block ?

Comment: it is taking the same image for the second time also, not displaying the two different images

Comment: @RahulSutar Provided try catch in my original answer, thanks for pointing that. Still if you see only one image in Grid, then it would be helpful if you post some sample code of BindGrid() method.

Comment: Please see the updated question..!!! Also, I am seeing the same image with different image name. Also the image name is getting inserted with different names in the table with two different rows.

Comment: @RahulSutar Can you put a break point in BindGrid() method and see how many records are filled in DataTable/DataSet?

Comment: @SivaGopal: Hi, just came inside office..Will update you with debugging.!!

Comment: @SivaGopal: My `BindGrid()` is showing proper data at `dt`

Comment: @RahulSutar That means, your binding has some problem. As a cross check apart from other html verification, though silly, but just see if the height of grid is less than it is supposed to be..

Comment: @RahulSutar Also you may take another test Grid with AutoGenerateColumns=True and check if you can see all the expected data.

Comment: @SivaGopal: I just changed the `FileUpload1.SaveAs` to `file.SaveAs` for getting different Images as expected and it is working. Now I just want that if multiple images are uploaded it should come in only row.

Comment: @RahulSutar That's an excellent finding, and it should fix most of your problems. Kudos!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68261/discussion-between-rahul-sutar-and-siva-gopal).

Answer (score 0):

Close your connection after execute your query.

```
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//Close connection
conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving the exception because you never close your connection. An `SqlConnection` generally can only ever execute one command at a time. Simply add:

```
conn.Close();
```

Comment: yes it is working, but I am unable to view multiple images in my gridview